# RabbitMQ docker run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

Currently, I am running a 3 node rabbitmq cluster using the following docker-compose file.

```
rabbit1:
  image: rabbitmq-server:0.0.1
  hostname: rabbit1
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=root
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=root
    - HOSTNAME=rabbit1

rabbit2:
  image: rabbitmq-server:0.0.1
  hostname: rabbit2
  links:
    - rabbit1
  environment: 
   - CLUSTERED=true
   - CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1
   - RAM_NODE=true
   - HOSTNAME=rabbit2
  ports:
      - "5673:5672"
      - "15673:15672"

rabbit3:
  image: kumar/rabbitmq-server:0.0.1
  hostname: rabbit3
  links:
    - rabbit1
    - rabbit2
  environment: 
   - CLUSTERED=true
   - CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1
   - HOSTNAME=rabbit3
  ports:
        - "5674:5672"
```

This is the script that the Dockerfile contains to start the containers and form a cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash

change_default_user() {
    
    if [ -z $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER ] && [ -z $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS ]; then
        echo "Maintaining default 'guest' user"
    else 
        echo "Removing 'guest' user and adding ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}"
        rabbitmqctl delete_user guest
        rabbitmqctl add_user $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
        rabbitmqctl set_user_tags $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER administrator
        rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / $RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER ".*" ".*" ".*"
    fi
}

if [ -z "$CLUSTERED" ]; then
    # if not clustered then start it normally as if it is a single server
    /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server &
    rabbitmqctl wait /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@$HOSTNAME.pid
    change_default_user 
    tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit\@$HOSTNAME.log
else
    if [ -z "$CLUSTER_WITH" ]; then
        # If clustered, but cluster with is not specified then again start normally, could be the first server in the
        # cluster
        /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server &
        rabbitmqctl wait /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@$HOSTNAME.pid
        tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit\@$HOSTNAME.log
    else
        /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server &
        rabbitmqctl wait /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit\@$HOSTNAME.pid
        rabbitmqctl stop_app
        if [ -z "$RAM_NODE" ]; then
            rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@$CLUSTER_WITH
        else
            rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@$CLUSTER_WITH
        fi
        rabbitmqctl start_app
                
        # Tail to keep the a foreground process active..
        tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit\@$HOSTNAME.log
    fi
fi
```

I need to convert the docker-compose into docker run commands and start all three containers in a clustered format. The problem I am facing is that I need to have a single run command which can be used to start all containers one by one differentiating only by name and form a cluster as well. How do I pass the commands like **--link** and some specific environment variable in such a way that single run command can accomdate all.

```
docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.11 --hostname rab1 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --add-host rab3:172.18.0.13 --name rab1con -p 15672:15672 -e HOSTNAME=rab1 kumar/rabbitmq-server:0.0.1


docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.12 --hostname rab2 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --add-host rab3:172.18.0.13 --name rab2con -p 15673:15672 -e HOSTNAME=rab2 -e CLUSTERED=true -e CLUSTER_WITH=rab1 kumar/rabbitmq-server:0.0.1

docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 172.18.0.13 --hostname rab3 --add-host rab1:172.18.0.11 --add-host rab2:172.18.0.12 --name rab3con -p 15674:15672 -e HOSTNAME=rab3 -e CLUSTERED=true -e CLUSTER_WITH=rab1 kumar/rabbitmq-server:0.0.1
```

These are the 3 docker commands that can be used to start the containers and also form the cluster. Is there anyway to make it generic so I can remove -e CLUSTERED=true -e CLUSTER_WITH=rab1

Comment: Can you explain more about why you're unable to use `docker-compose`?

Comment: The script we are using to start the cluster will reside on 3 different machines and using the docker run the containers will start on these machines and should join the cluster. The problem is the script with the run command should be identical and I am not sure how to form the run command so the nodes which starts later can join the cluster

Comment: Use your cluster orchestrator, k8s, Docker swarm etc. Manually managing the lifecycle of containers will be more difficult and won't scale

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker run -d --name=rabbit1 -h rabbit1 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=root -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=root -e HOSTNAME=rabbit1 rabbitmq:3 && docker run --name=rabbit2 -d -h rabbit2 --link rabbit1 -p 5673:5672 -p 15673:15672 -e CLUSTERED=true -e CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1 -e RAM_NODE=true -e HOSTNAME=rabbit2 rabbitmq:3 && docker run --name=rabbit3 -d -h rabbit3 --link rabbit1 --link rabbit2 -p 5674:5672 -e CLUSTERED=true -e CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1 -e HOSTNAME=rabbit3 rabbitmq:3 && sleep 15 && docker run -it --name=bash --link rabbit1 --link rabbit2 --link rabbit3 bash

41fa0f064aefd6382d1d20b9b716df3ebb21b99b44882f8cf3ffb1e789103d5d
87c1fec7a8eadbe7745f9496bc53935a5e8ddaa68b90c2b4faaaf8843f2dd5a0
9dc4e612c993df4aeacffc384c6c445d5d3ecef3ec5bea73797f6a33809c52f1

bash-5.1# ping rabbit1
PING rabbit1 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms
--- rabbit1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.125/0.127/0.130 ms
bash-5.1# ping rabbit2
PING rabbit2 (172.17.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.243 ms
--- rabbit2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.132/0.187/0.243 ms
bash-5.1# ping rabbit3
PING rabbit3 (172.17.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.167 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.118 ms
--- rabbit3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.118/0.142/0.167 ms
bash-5.1# nc -zv rabbit2 5672
rabbit2 (172.17.0.3:5672) open
```

```
docker ps
```

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                              NAMES
7fbd718c6c18   rabbitmq:3              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago    Up 4 seconds    4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15691-15692/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5674->5672/tcp                             rabbit3
9cdc70795d49   rabbitmq:3              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds    4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15691-15692/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5673->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15673->15672/tcp   rabbit2
f8533f132c59   rabbitmq:3              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15691-15692/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   rabbit1
```

I changed docker image to actual `rabbitmq:3` to be able run commands. Also I added `bash` container in the end of commands chain to check if `rabbit{1,2,3}` available inside containers group.

Also docker-compose file may be converted into run command by [this service](https://8gwifi.org/dc2.jsp).
Don't forget to add manually `-d` and `--name=rabbit{1,2,3}` to `run` if you will use it.